# What File System to Use for 64gb Thumbdrive in Linux

Tags: linux, filesystems, usb-flash-drive

I have a 64 GB thumbdrive that I would like to use on a CentOS 5.4 Linux machine that does not seem to support NTFS. What file system should I format it as? I want to be able to use this thumbdrive in Windows as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up formatting my drive as FAT32 with [EaseUS Partition Master Home Edition](http://download.cnet.com/EaseUS-Partition-Master-Free-Edition/3000-2248_4-10863346.html).

Answer (score 3):

*CentOS 5.4* is 3.5 years old but you [can install](http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/NTFS) the `ntfs-3g` package to gain NTFS read and write support. The ntfs-3g driver is very good despite being FUSE.

```
yum install fuse fuse-ntfs-3g
```

Alternatively you could partition the thumbdrive with both a NTFS and a EXT4 partition. I would not recommend any FAT filesystem (lack of journal, file size limitations, etc.).

There is also [ext2fs for Windows](http://www.fs-driver.org/) which has very buggy support for EXT2 and EXT3 file-systems.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Gparted, this frontend will allow you to format the USB with the FAT filesystem.

edit: or other fs if you prefer, I recommend having a look at the features and characteristics of each on wikipedia if your not familiar with them.

Answer (score 1):

Which linux distro are you using? Most new ones handle ntfs just fine. If it is exclusively for linux, then you can just use a native linux fs such as ext3 or ext4. If you also wants to read it in other platforms such as Windows and Mac, then NTFS would be a better choice.

If you really do not like to use NTFS and still want to share files between different OSes, then you can try vfat32.

Comment: CentOS 5.4 is what I'm using. (Updated my question with those details). I do want to use it cross-platform so I will give vfat32 a try.

Comment: ntfs should work fine with centos 5.4 if you install fuse-ntfs-3g, though vfat32 might be safer as the centos 5 kernel is quite old and I am not sure how good the kernel module supports ntfs.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best choice would be to use *ntfs* file system (*as already mentioned*).

To mount any NTFS based filesystem, you need to install a tool called [NTFS3g](http://pkgs.repoforge.org/fuse-ntfs-3g/).

Make sure you have the rpmforge repo installed. If not, refer to [`Repositories`](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/RPMForge).
Install the following packages.

```
yum install fuse fuse-ntfs-3g
```

If the rpmforge repo is disabled by default:

```
yum --enablerepo=rpmforge install fuse fuse-ntfs-3g
```

See [reference](http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/NTFS).